# TypeScript type definition for function that wraps async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, higher-order-functions

I have a function takes takes an arbitrary async function and returns the result of awaiting that async function, but wrapped in a try/catch which adds some additional logic. See [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCwCwAYCMAlApgEwQCddgoFwYBeAWACgZGYAeAFRlwA8pcx8IYACgB0ogIZEA5hABcMMWACeAbQC6ASmoA%20GAAUiIALYIIuZgsVatg%20kzsxgYgDZO5rW03VzBI8VNl6EmKGuDxEEGxamlQ6eFAArkRgrIoADmasUdoejAD0uTAAAlAQALRc6WTlRAZEOfIQimDAQqLCEtJyukEhYRGZXjBxiclpGToxMADe9XZQRIrTs-aMJAlJ8nBiSA7OTr7t-uoA3MuMAL67UMDIQrg1IESaMwwr9ggAZkKC97UN8kp1MJkFAoKkAMpQMQJARUOEwDCYZ5nN55Ar4EAwCBGXBYhIfL7Ie64FF2c70UlMFAGOAcB5EU6vFbkpkwc6M%20gIMBhD5iYC4gCqpiIS1ZCHwcmgRC5kkZdjAwVwkvmMsZLM53PuvP5MAAkjxDN1FE4QGJ8KK7B8ELgnPhMMrpWBZfUrTb8AAmB2q%20jquhcnl83H63CGPAQVLgUwWpjir1OuVMV22%2014x3O1lJj1x9O%200CQWDAJzW7nUaOMSShZhhiOQXApdLWRKuVMywb6IwmMzVyN1sY6F6o-IwE2SBAtKCY5A7YUAN3uAPNaxGMBIEHiTlgRJIKKXGwA5Hv-hYExcADT1CPQKu4cM9%20u4RtEZtSmWnmAAIxA%20EUcjwoCI%20DMC%20TpvhYURdAYximNet61ve-YokOI5jjAE4wFOsCzvOCiLqEy6ruum7EjueH7oeYgCMe9QsuyFJ0Hm0AwBWUBCvOVDwEgaBYHghAkGQFBgD40RaPUhbFlAwjMcwrFENYe5NgA%20pge7qPQJx0QxmFiHOwaGKWiAoIiPHEKQ5DgD4n7fnIulGiaZrCaJRa8BJl5QMwundrWcmKe6e5vpZiiqXQJxAA).

```
const with401Redirection =
    <T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(
        call: T
    ): ((...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>) =>
    // @ts-expect-error
    async (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
        try {
            return await call(...args);
        } catch (error) {
            if ((error as any).httpStatus === 401) {
                // do some stuff here
            }

            throw error;
        }
    };

interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

interface ItemPayload {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

interface ItemResponse {
    id: string;
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

const client = {
    get<ResponseType>(url: string): Promise<ResponseType> {
        // logic to hit server and return result here
        return '' as any;
    },
    post<ResponseType>(url: string, body: Record<string, any>): Promise<ResponseType> {
        // logic to hit server and return result here
        return '' as any;
    }
};

const getUser = with401Redirection(() =>
    client.get<User>('url_1')
);

const saveItem = with401Redirection((body: ItemPayload) =>
    client.post<ItemResponse>('url_2', body)
);
```

I feel like the `// @ts-expect-error` in `with401Redirection` shouldn't be necessary -- how can I remove it or generally clean up the typing of the `with401Redirection` function? Keep in mind I want to maintain the fact that the `getUser` and `saveItem` functions have their types automatically inferred for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg7gQwJbAgEwDwBUB8UC8UWUEAHqgHZoDOUACgE4D2AtktRADJIDWEGSCgDMIDKAFU8AfliIU6DJKgAuIgG4AsAChQkWNRAUAxgDEKBKAAoAdLYQMA5tVUIKIANoBdAJQE8jVnZ+VxAcTS1tIQBXY2AkJnM4FAALABYABgBGACV0JAYIIziEqGwScggqWhgDYzMcSyMEABtm1SxvVRs7R2d6ewQWCFQGamwcX3x-ZjYODHhkVExc4CiGCixwflwcPABvbSgjqALV9agEWqMrW2t7J1U6AaGRsdxJ-cPj7+AGECgDlpvsDjqc1uYEHJgFAmq1undet5wiCjgBfL4gprAIzJKxkIwQMDFCi+QEo4FIIRWXQQJhU-GE4kEfCEADkTAARgArQrAVlQABkArxpAJRPiENoIW8UmsyWAwDAAGVgAhVrQWYQMplSRjycCAPQGqBoJhQaisaDUVZCKnJUQQPXk9FA-VHYDJZhwcpi4nIlEu76o8Iu7SCEZCBAEiQcMRk45INCqa0MQQOf1HCiDCDJ35pkPaMMUCNR6AASVQLCeIGaTAQaABeqESAgzTQmVzqYo6abLbbACZO-ntKGtOHRJHoxWICxctQwAkOI3XUdE0PuxmoM3W+31z2V1u+2hB+a8xuR4WtEZF9CjM0W8WLPGjg5hhg5wuKBxNpAGms2qeXYOJ09AzEE74QPOi4QD+ECfAe3xGlAtYOEg1zAGayQoOaogAG6iBcVAnMM4LEdQUTNNC9oFE6oIkecrL8pchEgJuqIADR6gu1oQVBX4wVsf4MABKZpuxUAckwaAgKouTXgwmCid24khBMjxgXMH7QbB8HkkhKFoVAGFQFh0KxvhYiuA2YLnAU5GUSZDq0UcNnmIxFxSm4bEjuE2jXl+0KvsA4ixhYSQetquRoPkvISpYlgfHqd4PsA1hBYosYNKy-4APqZKy3jaEil7+da5oIPh04sGFKSRXkBRFHFliSdJqhVdWtb1olB7JZUqXccAGBVVp-FZbl-asuJLUgIVWhIkAA)

```ts
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? Awaited<U> : T;
type AsyncFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;

function with401Redirection <T extends AsyncFn>(call: T): (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> {
    return async (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
        try {
            return await call(...args);
        }
        catch (exception) {
            if (typeof exception === 'object' && (exception as any)?.httpStatus === 401) {
                // do some stuff here
            }
            throw exception;
        }
    };
}
```

> Read about the actual, upcoming `Awaited` type in TS 4.5:
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements

Comment: How could I make this work if I want to chain nested async function wrappers?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950145/typescript-type-definition-for-function-that-wraps-async-function/69950410?noredirect=1#comment137879043_69950410) @David Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).